# Ellipsis Text Overflow on Float and Inline Block Elements

Tags: html, css, frontend, css-float, overflow

I am having trouble producing an ellipsis effect when a series of span children overflows its parent container. I have set up the parent container to have all the necessary attributes for an ellipsis (nowrap, display, hidden overflow, and of course text-overflow as ellipsis) but with my current setup, my spans seem to not want to ellipse on an overflow.
...The elements are structured like this

```
<div class="outer">
<span class="genre">Adventure</span>
<span class="operator">OR</span>
<span class="genre"> Comedy</span>
</div>
```

...And the corresponding CSS:

```
.outer {
    max-width: 90px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: inline-block;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.operator {
  width: 20px;
  height: 22px;
  float: left;
}
.genre {
  float: left;
}
```

While the desired effect is an ellipsis, what I'm seeing is the overflowed elements wrapping around instead. I was under the impression that any sort of wrapping would be prevented through my display as inline-block, as well as nowrap, but that doesn't seem to be the case here. This seems to be due to floating the elements, but what I've been looking for is a solution that **includes** these floats in this case. Here is a jsfiddle of my current situation: https://jsfiddle.net/k91wzsq3/2/  - And The screenshot below is the effect I'm looking for.

[image: This is the desired outcome]

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use the float property in this case, it will just mess up your element. You only needed to tell the `.outer` element that it is going to be inline, just like you did but then by adding the floats it broke everything. You only need this on you CSS

```
.outer {
  max-width: 90px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/zgranda/0Ls6fw4j/14/